# Plot growth of 100 when return is given. Highstocks

Tags: highcharts, mschart

I would like to populate a chart where y-axis is plotted as a growth of 1000. I.e., if I have a data say [01-Jan-2014,1.23],[02-Jan-2014,1.03],[03-Jan-2014,0.23]....[10-Aug-2014,-0.65]
Then my first point would be x: 1st Jan y:  1000 and next point is on x: 2nd-Jan y: 1000(1 + 1.03) next is x: 3rd-Jan-2014 y: 1000(1+1.03)(1+0.23)...and so on.

This should be the same even if I change the dates using a range selector. That is always my chart has to start from 1000 and the growth from that date should be plotted.

A working example of this using MS chart is present at this link
http://www.morningstar.in/mutualfunds/f00000pe1t/hdfc-top-200-fund--direct-plan-dividend-option/overview.aspx

How to achieve this using highstocks.

Comment: So when you use rangeselector and call i.e 1m, then data should be recalculated to formula 1000(1+1.03) ?

Comment: Yes, so say the selected range is from 18 July 2014 to 18 Aug 2014. Then the data at 18th July would be 1000 and 19th would be 1000(1 + (growth % on 19th)). and so on which in the above case was 1.03.

Comment: Please go through the link and just change the period, you will get it better that way. Thanks.

Comment: In general you can catch [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.setExtremes) and then call [series.update]() or [setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData) to calculate your data.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, that would sort the issue but as you might be aware, after update series the chart takes some time to redraw and moreover at every setExtremes I need to loop through all the existing data to create new. This takes a lot of time in jquery and not desirable.

Comment: Why not just preprocess the data to get the desired Y-values before creating the chart?

Comment: Because the desired data changes at change of date. So, if I have to preprocess the data I have to capture the change event and either go back to database fetch the data accordingly or do the calculation at client side. I am looking if there is any alternative because doing this gives a complete redraw look to the chart and range slider doesn't serve the process.